# firebase ANR due to deadblock

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, crittercism

After I upgraded Firebase-cloud-messaging SDK and Crittercism SDK at the same time, My App ANR has a very high ANR rate. ANR happened during the launch.

My dependencies config is:

```
implementation 'com.crittercism:crittercism-android-ndk-agent:5.8.7'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
```

Here is ANR stack log:

> The "Measurement Worker" (tid=9), "Thread-33751" (tid=11) threads are in a deadlock.

```
"Measurement Worker" prio=5 tid=9 Blocked
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c023a0 self=0xadd8a600
  | sysTid=25249 nice=10 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xb2b7f930
  | state=S schedstat=( 235085574 45426929 104 ) utm=15 stm=8 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0xb2a7d000-0xb2a7f000 stackSize=1038KB
  | held mutexes=

  at java.security.Provider.getService (Provider.java:378)
- waiting to lock <0x04938828> (a com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLProvider) held by thread 11

  at java.security.Security$SecurityDoor.getService (Security.java:424)

  at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Services.getFirstServiceOfType (Services.java:164)
- locked <0x0d3d5941> (a java.lang.Class<org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Services>)

  at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Services.getCacheVersion (Services.java:197)
- locked <0x0d3d5941> (a java.lang.Class<org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Services>)

  at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getServices (Engine.java:159)

  at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance (Engine.java:137)

  at java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance (MessageDigest.java:91)

  at com.google.firebase.iid.w.a (unavailable)

  at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.c (unavailable)

  at com.google.android.gms.c.cb.D (unavailable)

  at com.google.android.gms.c.cb.a (unavailable)

  at com.google.android.gms.c.fa.a (unavailable)

  at com.google.android.gms.c.fa.a (unavailable)

  at com.google.android.gms.c.dg.c (unavailable)

  at com.google.android.gms.c.dh.run (unavailable)

  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:423)

  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)

  at com.google.android.gms.c.df.run (unavailable)


"Thread-33751" prio=5 tid=11 Blocked
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c020a0 self=0xb47a4f00
  | sysTid=25257 nice=0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0xae16a930
  | state=S schedstat=( 34997241 16589583 36 ) utm=1 stm=2 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xae068000-0xae06a000 stackSize=1038KB
  | held mutexes=

  at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Services.setNeedRefresh (Services.java:187)
- waiting to lock <0x0d3d5941> (a java.lang.Class<org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Services>) held by thread 9

  at java.security.Provider.remove (Provider.java:284)
- locked <0x04938828> (a com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLProvider)

  at com.crittercism.internal.i.b (unavailable:195)

  at com.crittercism.internal.i.a (unavailable:141)

  at com.crittercism.internal.am$a.run (unavailable:2040)

  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```